# how to access anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, webmatrix

```
List<Object> testimonials = new List<Object>();
testimonials.Add(new {
    Author = "Author 1",
    Testimonial = "Testimonial 1"
});
testimonials.Add(new {
    Author = "Author 2",
    Testimonial = "Testimonial 2"
});
testimonials.Add(new {
    Author = "Author 3",
    Testimonial = "Testimonial 3"
});

@ObjectInfo.Print(testimonials[DateTime.Now.DayOfYear % testimonials.Count].Author)
```

Gives me an error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Author'

How do I get only the Author or Testimonial from the list of testimonials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lazy way would be to switch "object" for "dynamic". Or use A Tuple generic type.

But IMO you should simply write a class with hear two properties:

```
public class Testimonial {
    public string Author {get;set;}
    public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

And use a List-of-Testimonial.

Another way would be to use something like:

```
var arr = new[]{new{...},new{...}};
```

This is an array of your anon-type, and;

```
string author = arr[0].Author;
```

Would work fine.

Comment: +1 Anonymous types are very useful, but in this scenario you should define a strict type.

Answer (score 0):

Use implicitly-typed array:

```
var arr = new[]
{
    new { Author = "Author 1", Testimonial = "Testimonial 1" },
    new { Author = "Author 2", Testimonial = "Testimonial 2" },
    new { Author = "Author 3", Testimonial = "Testimonial 3" }
};
// .ToList() if needed, however array supports indexer

string author = arr[i].Author;
```